# Blank page pops up when using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm making an appointment booking app. The problem is when I click "book appointment", it's supposed to take me to a page where the form is to book the appointment. I haven't made the form yet because I noticed nothing pops up when I click the link. (I'm supposed to see an h1 tag containing text that says "bookingPage"). There are only 2 routes.

App.jsx

```
import {  Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import BookingPage from "./pages/home/bookingPage/BookingPage"
import Home from "./pages/home/Home"

const App = () => {
  return (

      <Routes>
      { <Route index element={<Home />} /> }
        <Route path='/booking' component={BookingPage} />

      </Routes>

  )
}

export default App
```

The first route contents all my components

Home.jsx

```
import ContactSection from "../../Sections/Contact/ContactSection"
import FAQsSection from "../../Sections/FAQs/FAQsSection"
import Footer from "../../Components/Footer"
import Header from "../../Components/Header"
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar"
import PolicySection from "../../Sections/Policy/PolicySection"
import HeaderImage from '../../images/zamia.jpeg'
import PricesSection from "../../Sections/Prices/PricesSection"

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Header title="Welcome Bossy Dolls !" image={HeaderImage}>
        Please read the following terms and contions before booking appointment.
      </Header>
      <PricesSection />
      <PolicySection />
      <ContactSection />
      <FAQsSection />
      <Footer />
 
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

And the second route contains a simple

BookingPage.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './BookingPage.css'

const BookingPage = () => {
  return (
    <h1 className='bookingHeader'>BookingPage</h1>
  )
}

export default BookingPage
```

I did what I usually do which is wrap the  around  tags

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
    </BrowserRouter>  
)
```

But for some reason when I click a link that leads me to the booking page no components pop up. I tried removing the routes tags in the App.jsx but that only crashes the site. I also tried adding a path & component attribute to the first route in App.jsx but that also crashes the site. I'm not sure what else to do. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are mixing two versions of `react router (v5 & V6)` . And it seems  you are using  **react router v6**

Just **change :**

`<Route path='/booking' component={BookingPage} />` in the **App.jsx** file

**to  :**

```
 <Route path="/booking" element={<BookingPage />} />
```

Comment: It worked ! thanks so much.. btw which version of react-router-dom is the one with the element attribute ?

Comment: great ! `react router v6`